# Build docker container for Mysql 8.0 fail

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I need create a docker container for several projects tha use Mysql 8.0 with PHP 7.3

I like create it, because I need modify mysql startup configuration

For this I create

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:8.0

COPY mysqld_charset.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_charset.cnf

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="123456"
```

**mysqld_charset.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin = mysql_native_password
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

License and readme files.

**Execute**

```
$ docker build --no-cache -t mysql8_legacy_password .                                                                     
Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.85kB
Step 1/3 : FROM mysql:8.0
 ---> 62a9f311b99c
Step 2/3 : COPY mysqld_charset.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_charset.cnf
 ---> 0e21143ae822
Step 3/3 : ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="123456"
 ---> Running in a8d350dbd651
Removing intermediate container a8d350dbd651
 ---> 7dd66b27be00
Successfully built 7dd66b27be00
Successfully tagged mysql8_legacy_password:latest

$  docker run --name mysql8_legacy_password  -it mysql:8.0                                                                
error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified 
  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the run command.

`docker run --name mysql8_legacy_password  -it mysql:8.0`

You are trying to start a container from `mysql:8.0` image in which no env has been setup.

The last argument of the `docker run` command should be the image name. Since you have tagged your image as `mysql8_legacy_password`, this should work:

`docker run --name container_name  -it mysql8_legacy_password`

[docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Comment: Thanks. A mistake with docker -run